# SQLAlchemy retreiving data from db as list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sql, flask

i'm trying to retreive data from SQLAlchemy (flask_sqlalchemy) as a list of dictionaries, each row in db should be a dict.

expected result should be like this:

```
result = [{'id':val1, 'location:val2, 'event':val3, 'date_created': val4, 'background':val5},{'id':val11, 'location:val12, 'event':val13, 'date_created': val14, 'background':val15}]
```

idea is to use data later like this:

```
data = result[i]['location']
print(data)
```

my db model looks like this:

```
class events_db(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    event = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    background = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
```

and I'm doing query like this:

```
 events = events_db.query.order_by(events_db.date_created)
```

events variable is a type:

```
<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>
```

so, question is how to retreive values from this class in expected form.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an .all() after your query, and this:

```
events = events_db.query.order_by(events_db.date_created).all()
results_dict = [dict((col, getattr(row, col)) for col in row.__table__.columns.keys()) for row in events]
```